# docker-compose race condition when running in CI

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose smoke test I run in CI....when two builds of the same project get executed simultaneously the build usually fails.  I'm sure the builds are getting executed concurrently on the same machine with a shared docker socket.  it appears that docker-compose tries to reuse/access containers from the other instance and ends up in some sort of race condition.

I've tried various flags to solve this problem, but still get failures.  Current flags are: `--exit-code-from smoke --remove-orphans --force-recreate
using --exit-code-from implies --abort-on-container-exit`

How do I keep these two instances of build containers to be isolated from one another?

Here is an example of a failure:

```
+ make smoke
ls: /var/lib/docker/volumes/0_3542251907521744511_default/_data: No such file or directory
ls: '/var/lib/docker/volumes/0_3542251907521744511_default/_data'/src/github.myco.com/viper-ace/psn-router/'}: No such file or directory
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad0 docker-py version: 3.6.0 CPython version: 2.7.15 OpenSSL version: LibreSSL 2.7.4
docker-compose -f smoke-test/docker-compose.yaml up --exit-code-from smoke --remove-orphans --force-recreate
using --exit-code-from implies --abort-on-container-exit
Recreating mock-maker ... 
Recreating mock-maker ... done
Recreating psn-router ... 
Recreating psn-router-500 ... 
Recreating psn-router-500 ... done
Recreating psn-router     ... done
Recreating smoke          ... 
Attaching to mock-maker, psn-router-500, psn-router, smoke
mock-maker                 | > mock-maker@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
psn-router-500             | 2019-04-11T16:36:21.411Z level=INFO, code=0000, src=psn-router/server.go:87, s=psn-router, hostname=psn-router-instance, c=UNKNOWN, site=UNKNOWN, m="Listen and Serve: http://127.0.0.1:8080"
mock-maker                 | > node mock-maker.js
psn-router                 | 2019-04-11T16:36:21.441Z level=INFO, code=0000, src=psn-router/server.go:87, hostname=psn-router-instance, c=UNKNOWN, site=UNKNOWN, s=psn-router, m="Listen and Serve: http://127.0.0.1:8080"
mock-maker                 | MockMaker app listening at http://:::80
Unexpected API error for psn-router (HTTP code 404)
Response body:
{"message":"No such container: 89460559a3e81a230f5647d52997c5b05bf94f3bdc8e268ca9654d3945ca675d"}
Recreating smoke          ... done
Stopping psn-router-500   ... 
Stopping mock-maker       ... 
Stopping psn-router-500   ... done
Stopping mock-maker       ... done
No such container: 8dec60de6fb3657c0a70e9d53aa27e385b9bd50c24e6cb332d1a7cc373bb7afa
Aborting on container exit...
make: *** [Makefile:22: smoke] Error
```

here is the docker-compose file:

```
services:
  mock-maker:
    container_name: "mock-maker"
    image: registry.myco/viper-ace/mock-maker:0.11.0
  psn-router-500-endpoint:
    container_name: "psn-router-500"
    image: "${DOCKER_IMAGE}"
    depends_on:
      - mock-maker
    environment:
      - ENDPOINT= http://mock-maker/endpoint500 
  psn-router:
    container_name: "psn-router"
    image: "${DOCKER_IMAGE}"
    depends_on:
      - mock-maker
    environment:
      - ENDPOINT= http://mock-maker/endpoint200 
  smoke:
    container_name: "smoke"
    image: registry.myco/http-blackbox-test-tool:2.0.2
    depends_on:
      - psn-router
    volumes:
       - ${SMOKE_TEST_DIR}:/smoke-test
    environment:
      - TEST_DIR=/smoke-test
```

make target:

```
smoke:
    @echo $(shell docker-compose version)
    SMOKE_TEST_DIR=$(CODE_DIR)/smoke-test DOCKER_IMAGE=${DOCKER_IMAGE} docker-compose -f smoke-test/docker-compose.yaml up --exit-code-from smoke --remove-orphans --force-recreate
```

Comment: Can you please provide your Makefile

Comment: updated the question with the make target

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are facing is due to the fact that `docker-compose` uses whats called project name to "link" containers to a specific `docker-compose` invocation.

Here is what the `docker-compose` documentation says about project name:

> **COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME**
>
> Sets the project name. This value is prepended along with the service name to the container on start up. For example, if your project name is myapp and it includes two services db and web, then Compose starts containers named myapp_db_1 and myapp_web_1 respectively.
>
> Setting this is optional. If you do not set this, the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME defaults to the basename of the project directory. See also the -p command-line option.

So in your case what is happening is that if you have two `docker-compose` commands attempting to run simultaneously on the same machine using the same directory they will both have project the name: `smoke_test`.

This means if two invocations of `make smoke` happen simultaneously they will both see containers with the `smoke_test` prefix and try to manage/recreate them as they believe they belong to them, when in fact they may not.

**Solution:**

The easiest solution for you would to be specify a unique project-name for each invocation of `make smoke` using the `--project-name` flag for `docker-compose`.

One way to do this would be:

`docker-compose --project-name $(data +'%s') -f smoke-test/docker-compose.yaml up --exit-code-from smoke --remove-orphans --force-recreate`

This way each invocation of `docker-compose` will have its containers isolated from other simultaneous invocations of `make smoke`.

As an aside I think a preferred way to generate unique project names would to be use something like a build number, instead of a unix timestamp.

Hopefully this helps.